# keep hold of data.d value after window.location command on ajax success

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am working on some code that is effectively a mini search box on website A that will take some input and then route through to website B. Website B will then show results based on the search criteria used on website A.

I have a web method on website B that is ready to take the parameters. I call this webmethod from site A and I can see that the query is executing fine. My issue is that the result of the web method is a string of html that is then put to the .html attribute of a Div on Site B. The html isnt the entire page, infact it is literally just the search results.

What I need to ideally do is redirect to that page & inject that html in to the div. All from the main ajax call on site A.

This is my code: (called from site a)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://siteb.com/default.aspx/doSearch',
    data: jdata,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        window.location = "http://www.siteb.com/default.aspx";
        $("#pageContentWrapper").html(data.d);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("An error happened while getting the search");
    }
});
```

So pageContentWrapper is where I want the data.d results to be rendered. All works fine until window.location goes off to site b, where I think data.d goes out of context and I get the main default page without any search results.

Is there a way I can hold the context of data.d right through to the completion of the ajax request or is there a better way entirely of doing this?

Many thanks

Comment: And why are you doing an ajax call, and then redirecting, in this case that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an issue of context.  When you call `window.location`, you are navigating the browser to an entirely different page.  Any javascript that you are running (in this case `$("#pageContentWrapper").html(data.d)`) is going to be stopped entirely.  You need to find some other way to pass the information you would like to maintain, either by passing it in URL params (`http://www.siteb.com/default.aspx?query=some_query`) or rendering the content on site b without forcing a page redirect

Answer (score 0):

Wy don't you do this:

```
http://www.siteb.com/search.aspx?s=What it A
```

And then complete the search on site B?